# Importing Ledger hardware wallet addresses to Nami

Tags: nami-wallet, yoroi, ledger

I'm having issues importing and seeing my Ledger hardware wallet addresses with Nami. I would be interested to know if anyone else is in a similar situation to the one described below and if they have found a solution to this problem.

I set up my Yoroi wallet with my Ledger hardware wallet and, after setting it up in the default way, which created one address, I then manually got Yoroi to create a 2nd address.

So I now had two addresses on my Yoroi wallet that were both integrated with my
Ledger and could only be used through that.

I recently tried using a DApp that doesn't support Ledger-integrated Yoroi wallets but does support Nami, so I tried to set up Nami to use those same two ADA addresses that I had originally set up on my Ledger wallet. So I went to Nami -> Connect Hardware Wallet and was then prompted to select the accounts that I wanted to add. I was given the option to add "Account 1 - Default", in addition to 49 other accounts, all numbered sequentially from 2 to 50. I added all 50 accounts.

I noticed that my 1st ledger-integrated Yoroi address was imported across to Nami as "Account 1 - default", however my 2nd Yoroi wallet address wasn't imported into Nami as Account 2 or any other of the 48 accounts that were set up. It seems that Account 2 to Account 49 were just new addresses that Nami had generated. I couldn't see my 2nd Yoroi wallet address anywhere in the Nami wallet.

When connecting my Nami wallet to the DApp, if I connect using Account 1 (i.e. my 1st Yoroi/Ledger address that I imported across to Nami) then I don't experience any issues and the DApp correctly shows the connected address.

My issue is this however: I can't get Nami to see the 2nd address that I set up on my Yoroi wallet. For some reason, I can't seem to get Nami to import this address too.

This person seems to have a similar problem - https://forum.cardano.org/t/restoring-nami-wallet-restored-wallet-with-different-address-and-0-funds/86632/130?page=4. Although in his case, he isn't using a hardware wallet, the similarity is that he is only able to restore the first address of his wallet on Nami using his seed phrase and the 2nd one is not appearing at all.

I've tried using Ledger Live and seeing how it deals with my two addresses - I've imported my cardano accounts into there and I've found that those two ADA addresses were imported as a single account and their transaction history were merged into one.

Another interesting point is that checking those two addresses on CardanoScan shows them as having the same Controlled Stake Key but each address shows it's own separate transaction history on CardanoScan.

I would be very interested to know if anyone has experienced the above issue and if they have a solution to it.

Many thanks

Comment: Nami uses one address per account, UTXOs in other addresses will be invisible. This true in general, not just for hardware wallets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour from Nami, as it only imports first address for a given account (a HD wallet can have multiple accounts and each account can have multiple addresses). You can read more about HD Wallets that you might be familiar with (and is seen by Ledger Live too) [here](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/concepts/hierarchical-deterministic-wallets). This is also documented on [their website](https://namiwallet.io/) under `Is Nami compatible with Daedalus/Yoroi`.

If you want to access full wallet contents, You can - however - import your wallet to [eternl](https://eternl.io/) / [typhon](https://typhonwallet.io/#/) / [flint](https://flint-wallet.com/) to access complete HD Wallet.

Comment: Thanks very much, I used Eternl and it solved my issue!